# Is this a mistake in Dummit & Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring without identity, and let $a, b \in R$. Is it true that $b \in (a) \iff b=ar$ for some $r \in R$?

This seems to be implied (I can provide the details upon request) in Dummit & Foote.

The definition of $(a)$ provided in Dummit & Foote is the intersection of all ideals which contain $a$. In commutative rings with identity, it is proved that $(a) = R \{a \} R = \{r_1ar_2 + \cdots + \cdots r_nar_n| \text{ where each } r_i \in R  \} = \{ar | r \in R \}.$ In this case, it's easy to prove that $b \in (a) \iff b=ar$ for some $r \in R$.

However, I think this is not true in rings without identity, and I think I have a counterexample:

Let $R = 2 \mathbb{Z}$, and $a=6$. The only ideals of $R$ which contain $6$ are $2\mathbb{Z} = R$ and $6\mathbb{Z}$, so the intersection of all ideals which contain $6$ is $6\mathbb{Z}$.

Now $18 \in (6) = 6\mathbb{Z}$, but $18 \not = 6r$ for some $r \in 2\mathbb{Z}$.

**EDIT:** This is where I found the statement in D & F. I have the third edition, paperback. On page $274$, we have the definition of divisibility:

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $a,b \in R$ with $b \not = 0$.

$\vdots$

Note that $b|a$ in a ring $R$ if and only if $a \in (b)$ ...

(Sorry I reversed the roles of $a, b$ in my question)

Comment: Well, even $6$ itself does not seem to be a multiple of $6$ in $2\mathbb{Z}$.   But it would be more interesting to know why you have the sense Dummit and Foote suggested the quoted statement.

Comment: @CarlMummert To make sure I understand, are you saying that my counterexample is still correct but I could've just used $6$ instead of $18$? I will edit the question and add the statement from D & F.

Comment: Yes, exactly. ...

Comment: @CarlMummert I've edited the question. Sorry I've reversed the roles of $a, b$ in my question, but the problem still stands.

Comment: Ovi - are you sure they don't assume that rings have identities?

Comment: @CarlMummert Not as far as I can tell. Often in the beginning of each chapter or section they state the assumptions about all rings presented. For this one (chapter 8) it just says "All rings in this chapter are commutative".

Comment: @CarlMummert So in this occurance, should I just read it as if they meant commutative rings with identity?

Comment: @Ovi: Yes, I'd chalk this one up as an oversight by Dummit & Foote.

Comment: The book does have the assumption '$R$ has $1\neq 0$' at the beginning of section 7.4 where they defined $(A)$. But I still think they should state this again at the beginning of chapter 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Hat tip to Carl Mummert, who pointed out that my original answer used the wrong definition of the ideal generated by $a \in R$.

According to Dummit and Foote, the ideal generated by an element $a$ of a ring $R$, denoted $(a)$ is the smallest ideal containing $a$. When $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, then $(a) = Ra$, where $Ra = \{r a : r \in R \}$ is also an ideal.

The example you provide shows that $(a) \neq Ra$ in general when $R$ is a commutative ring without identity. Indeed, $(6)$ consists of all multiples of $6$, while $R6$ consists of all multiples of $12$ in your example.

You are correct that Dummit and Foote's statement is wrong in general. The correct version is $b \mid a \Leftrightarrow a \in Rb$, for any commutative ring $R$. When $R$ contains an identity, this is equivalent to $b \mid a \Leftrightarrow a \in (b)$, but their statement is strictly speaking false without the assumption that $R$ contains an identity, and your counterexample shows that. In your example, $18 \in (6)$ but $6 \nmid 18$ in $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The right definition seems to be $(a) = \{ na + r_1a + \cdots + r_ka : n \in \mathbb{Z}, r_1, \ldots, r_k \in R\}$.   Every element of this set must be in every ideal containing $a$, and conversely this set is an ideal containing $a$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: You're right. I'm using the wrong definition, and the smallest ideal containing $a$ is not the same as $Ra$ if $R$ does not contain an identity. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Please see the edit to the question. My quote is from chapter $8$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome, but sorry for the confusion. Thanks to @CarlMummert for the correction.